# Nullreference Exception while Instantiating object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void Shoot(float lastShot, float fireRate, GameObject bullet, Enemy enemyStats, Transform thisTransform)
{
    if (Time.time > lastShot + fireRate)
    {
        GameObject bulletToSpawn = bullet;
        GameObject bulletIns = Instantiate(bulletToSpawn.gameObject, thisTransform.position, thisTransform.rotation) as GameObject;
        bulletIns.GetComponent<Bullet>().enemyStats = enemyStats;
        lastShot = Time.time;
        Destroy(bulletIns, 20f);
    }
}
```

I also added a variable called `bulletToSpawn` to check if there's an issue getting the bullet gameobject. It seems I am able to get the bullet gameobject. But somehow `bulletIns` is still null. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the GameObjec look like? and what does Instantiate(..) do? I can see it has something to do with unity.. but you might want to elaborate on the problem and supply more details.. where does the exception occur?  and what does the stack contain?

Comment: Why are you using `Instantiate(bulletToSpawn.gameObject, thisTransform.position, thisTransform.rotation)` rather than just `Instantiate(bulletToSpawn, thisTransform.position, thisTransform.rotation)` since it is already a `GameObject`? Also have you confirmed that `thisTransform` is valid?

Comment: It would much easier to assist you if you could edit your question and include the full stacktrace you're getting.

Comment: if `bulletToSpawn` is a prefab, the `gameObject` property will be null, so you are instantiating nothing. You should just pass `bulletToSpawn` (or why not just pass bullet?) into `Instantiate` instead of calling the `gameObject` property.